# postgresql: .pgpass not working on Windows / cygwin

Tags: postgresql, cygwin, psql

**I cannot get .pgpass to work on Windows/cygin**

I have pgAdmin4 installed on Windows 10, psql version 12.0.

I am using cygwin, writing bash scripts to do various things to a PG database installed with a cloud provider.

If I specify these env vars in the bash script, everything works great:

```
export PGUSER=<pguser>
export PGPASSWORD=<pgpassword>
export PGHOSTADDR=<ip-address>
export PGPORT=5432
```

But if instead, I do not include those env vars in the bash script and create a .pgpass file:   $HOME/.pgpass and enter a line like:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

and run the script, it tries to connect to 'localhost', as if it can't find the .pgpass file.

---

**I get this error:**

```
Running: [./myscript.sql]

psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

---

**I tried specifying explicitely in the bash script like so:**

```
export PGPASSFILE=$HOME/.pgpass
```

and it still does not work, I get the same error message, it's ignoring the **PGPASSFILE** env variable.

---

**I set the permissions on the .pgpass file to be 0600, and so that is not the problem.**

```
ls -l .pgpass
-rw------- 1 <user> None 49 Feb 12 23:01 .pgpass
```

Comment: I would use Process Monitor to see where `psql` is looking for the file.

Comment: pgAdmin4 is not a Cywin program so what HOME means for it ? The suggestion of @LaurenzAlbe is a very good idea

Comment: 'psql' is a Windows program and I am running 'psql' which is a .exe complied for Windows.  I can run .exe programs inside of Cygwin because Cygwin is a Windows compiled application.

Comment: > I would use Process Monitor to see where psql is looking for the file.

I searched for Process Monitor, found it (Microsoft Sysinternals), downloaded and installed and it's a big piece of crap and does not let me do what you recommend.

I am assuming you use cygwin and have a $HOME/.pgpass in place and it's working?  Otherwise you would not have responded to this.

It freezes, it does not let me search and filter on any one process that I can see, I have a number of processes running and when I run my psql script, I can never find it in the list to follow this recommendation.

Comment: I have tried everything, there is no possible way to write a bash script, using 'psql.exe' and have it read the .pgpass file or pgpass.conf anywhere.  It's something that the developers of pgAdmin/psql left out on windows, was to read this file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel > Click on Administrative Tools > Open Services > Find postgresql-x64-13 and start the service.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkHff.png)

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using cygwin postgresql client 12.6.I tried everything mentioned here, no luck!

There is a workaround with db password on cygwin
try below psql call first, for my version of cygwin, I had to add single quote around password to make it work

```
psql postgresql://username:password@server:port:database
```

then add it to .bashrc in a function

```
function dbcall {
    psql postgresql://username:password@server:port:database
}
```

and don't forget: source .bashrc

problem solved!

Another alternative to workaround this is to try WSL. Microsoft fixed a lot of WSL issues since it was first launched.

Answer (score -1):

> run the script, it tries to connect to 'localhost', as if it can't find the .pgpass file.

.pgpass does not tell libpq (which is what psql uses) which host to connect to.  It is the opposite, libpq first determines the host, then looks for that specific host (or wildcard) within .pgpass.  So it seems like the broken thing here is PGHOSTADDR, not .pgpass.

Comment: It's not finding $HOME/.pgpass file.

I double checked the .pgpass file and PGHOSTADDR has an IP address set (nu.mb.er.s), it is not set to 'localhost'.

If PGHOSTADDR had the wrong IP, at a minimum it would say could not connect to that IP, but it is trying to use localhost, which is what it would use if it could not find a .pgpass file.

The HOME env var is set on Windows 10 in my personal env var settings.

Comment: The only response to this is wholly incorrect.  I have PGHOSTADDR set correctly in .pgpass.  If anyone has any idea and has .pgpass working on Windows under cygwin, I am open to new ideas.  No one anywhere is using Postgres on Windows with cygwin?

Comment: You said the problem exists when you don't set PGHOSTADDR in your script.  If it is not set, how can it be set to nu.mb.er.s?

Comment: "No one anywhere is using Postgres on Windows with cygwin?"  I have used it and it works, at least as far as `psql` goes.  .pgpass works, PGPASSFILE works, PGHOSTADDR works (if you set it).  The only problem seems to be that you made up a fictitious notion of how they work, and are unwilling to learn.

Comment: I don't believe you have it working.  Post a video of a bash script running in cygwin reading from .pgpass if you do, prove it.  I have PGHOSTADDR set correctly.  There is absolutely nothing in my comments where I suggest (as you suggest) how they work, I do not presume, nor did I post anything related to how they work or any misconception on how they work or anything from which could be derived that I am unwilling to learn - I have seen no informative response on how to get this to work or anything relevant that would help to this point.  I have PGHOSTADDR set correctly, & it works hard coded